# Lelong number of Ricci flat metric

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, calabi-yau, kahler-einstein-metric

Let $M$ be a compact Kahler Calabi-Yau variety which admit Ricci flat metric $\tilde\omega$, $Ric(\tilde \omega)=0$, then the Lelong number $\tilde \omega$ is zero?

In general if $\omega$ satisfies in the Kahler-Einstein equation $$Ric(\omega)=\lambda\omega$$ then is the Lelong number of $\omega$ vanishes?

Comment: From the asymptotic formula of $\omega$ which satisfies in KE metric we see that the growth of the metric is logarithmic. So the Lelong number vanishes,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Motto***: Canonical metric has vanishing Lelong number or (some times called Lelong-Demailly number)

Let me start with the definition of Lelong number.

Let
$W\subset \mathbb C^n$
be a domain, and $\Theta$ a positive current of degree $(q,q)$ on
$W$. For a point $p\in W$
one defines
$$\mathfrak v(\Theta,p,r)=\frac{1}{r^{2(n-q)}}\int_{|z-p|<r}\Theta(z)\wedge (dd^c|z|^2)^{n-q}$$
The
Lelong number
of $\Theta$ at
$p$
is defined as

$$\mathfrak v(\Theta,p)=\lim_{r \to 0}\mathfrak v(\Theta,p,r)$$

Let $\Theta$ be the curvature of singular hermitian metric $h=e^{-u}$, one has

$$\mathfrak v(\Theta,p)=\sup\{\lambda\geq 0: u\leq \lambda\log(|z-p|^2)+O(1)\}$$

By using Skoda-Lelong theory ,

If $X$ be a smooth projective variety and let $D$
be a nef and big $\mathbb R$-divisor on $X$.
Then the first Chern class $c_1(D)$ can be represented
by a closed positive (1,1)-current
$T$
with
$\mathfrak v(T)=0$

If there exists a modification
$f:Y\to X$ such that there exists a Zariski decomposition
$f^*L=P+N$
of
$f^*L$
on
$Y$.
Then
there
exists
a
closed
positive
$(1,
1)$
current
$S$
such
that
$c_1(P)=[S]$
and
$\mathfrak v(S)=0$

Since $c_1(X)=[Ric(\omega)]$ and $Ric(\omega)=\lambda\omega$ hence canonical metric has vanishing Lelong number

Moreover fibrewise Ricci flat metric and Weil-Petersson metric have $\omega_{SF}$ and $\omega_{WP}$ have zero Lelong number and hence when Kodaira dimension is positive then along $\pi:X\to X_{can}=\text{Proj }R(X,K_X)$
the canonical metric $\omega_{can}\in [-K_{X_{can}}+\pi_*(K_{X/X_{can}})]$ which satisfies in $$Ric(\omega_{can})=-\omega+\omega_{WP}$$ has vanishing Lelong number(here we used of this fact that direct image of relative line bundle plus anti-canonical bundle of base is nef and big)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question (or at least not the answer you gave it). It's an easy exercise to show that the Lelong number of any smooth $(p,p)$-form is zero. So what are you doing here?

Comment: In the sense of current I mean here

Comment: Is your Kahler metric singular?

Comment: I actually have no idea how your answer relates to the question you asked, nor what the pair $(X,D)$ is doing there, or what your $L$, $P$, $N$, $\omega$ are in it, or where $\omega_{can}$ or $\omega_{WP}$ come from. It's all quite mysterious.

Comment: See Zariski Decomposition and its connection with Analytical Zariski Decomposition of Demailly and Tsuji. I am sure that it must be trivial for you. P here is nef and N is effective divisor